# Can I have two identical websites over two domains, ideally running from same Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, dns, multiple-domains

Strange question. Basically I want to test out the success of two possible domain names, so I want to run a website duplicated over two domains. Is that possible?

So, for example, both WEBSITE1.com and WEBSITE2.com would have the exact same content coming from the same wordpress set up.

I know that a redirection is possible but that reverts to a different domain, which is not what i want.

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: This is a question about using features of Wordpress and does not belong on SO.  It belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com.  Further, you could have answered this question very easily yourself with basic research in the Wordpress codex.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress includes the ability to create a network of sites by using the multisite feature. This article contains instructions for creating a multisite network.

check below this link for how to set up  multidomain on WordPress 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Using this function, does it use the same content for all sites?

Comment: no, it basically doesn't. It uses the same files, but each site/domain has it's own content. It's somewhat easier to copy a base-site though...   
https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-clone-duplicator/
Probably not exactly what you want.
To my knowledge, using two domains on the same database/content is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? In `wp-config.php` add check for domain name and load different database credentials.

The problem will be when adding content.

Comment: "The problem will be when adding content." What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database

Ps. You will get duplicated content issue with Google if you index both sites in Google.

Comment: but thats still separate databases/installations.  it's basically simply two complete sets of tables with different prefixes.  not what OP looks for IMO.   he wants to run the same database, same data with two domains.